# Triangulable Spin 5-manifolds but do not admit any smooth structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology, spin-geometry

I noticed [the discussion in this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/319609/106497), which states that

> there are examples of D=5 spin manifolds which are triangulable, but do not admit any smooth structure.

What are some of these examples of D=5 spin manifolds?

Comment: As indicated in Mike Miller's answer, the product of the $E_8$ manifold with a circle is such an example.

Comment: But would E8 be spin manifold? would E8 be spin manifold in 4d as an example for Spin 4-manifolds but do not admit any smooth structure?

Comment: You have to define what you mean for a non-smooth manifold to be spin. The usual definition of spin requires a smooth structure, but one can show that a manifold is spin iff its first two Stiefel-Whitney classes vanish. One can define Stiefel-Whitney classes for any closed manifold (even if it isn't smoothable), so one could say that a closed manifold is spin if the first two Stiefel-Whitney classes vanish. With this definition, the $E_8$ manifold is a spin manifold. In particular, it is a four-dimensional spin manifold which does not admit a smooth structure, but it is not triangulable.

Comment: Thanks, this helps, +1, how do you show that E8 $\times S^1$ (which is spin) is triangulable then?

Comment: Again, this is in Mike Miller's answer: every compact orientable 5-manifold is triangulable (see Theorem 21.5 of Rudyak's paper).

Comment: Thanks I lack on your imagination to see why  E8 ×1 is triangulable, but E8 is non triangulable?

Comment: I don't think this stuff is easy to imagine, it's quite abstract.

Comment: so how do you convince yourself "why E8 ×1 is triangulable, but E8 is non triangulable? "

Comment: You prove the necessary theorems. Theorem 21.5 of Rudyak's paper shows that $E_8\times S^1$ is triangulable, and the equivalence between triangulable and smooth for four-manifolds shows that $E_8$ is not triangulable.